# How to get all the system configuration values in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, system-config

I need to get all the **fields and values** from

> Stores -> Configuration -> General

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('general');
```

where the `$this->scopeConfig` instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`

Here the complete example class:

```
class SystemValuesManager
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface 
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * SystemValuesManager constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $scope
     * @param null $scopeCode
     * @return array
     */
    public function getGeneralTabValues(
        $scope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
        $scopeCode = null
    ) {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general',
            $scope,
            $scopeCode
        );
    }
}
```

As a result you will see an array with all values from corresponding tab:

[image: result]